# Null value to move the row up in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data in format

```
    ID Name Jan Feb  Mar
    ---------------------
    1  xyz  1   null null
    1  xyz  2   null null 
    1  xyz  null  3  null
    1  xyz  null null 4
```

I need the data in below format in SQL Server 2008

```
 ID   Name   Jan Feb    Mar
 ----------------------------
  1     xyz     1    3     4
                2   null  null
```

Can anyone help?
I updated the question as id and name should not repeat.

Thanks

Comment: Does every column have only one value in the last three columns?  And why don't the first two columns have values?

Comment: Yes , the columns like jan ,feb have single values only. It is actually date column

Comment: What is the ID column. ID value should be different ????

Comment: Do you have any other column to differentiate those two rows.

Comment: The questions is incomplete and ambiguous.

Comment: I have only Id and name to distinguish @fireblade.  ID should not be different. It is the sample data of my resultset.

Comment: Why 3 and 4 are joined with 1, not with two? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: Because I need the data to be displayed from first row. @learningNew

Comment: @user3510028 What If ,
Last row is - 
    1  xyz  null  5    4    
How it will be dispalyed ?

Comment: then the output at last  will be 1 xyz 2 5 4

Comment: This data model looks suspicious. Is this a table? A record represents attributes that belong together, so `Jan=1` belongs to `Feb=null` for instance. Then in your results you combine `Jan=1` with `Feb=3` (and you could as well combine `Jan=2` with `Feb=3`, as records in a table have no inherent order). This makes me wonder: Do `Jan=1` and `Feb=null` really belong together or should they be in separate records in a table with four columns `id, name, month, value` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT ID, Name, [Jan], [Feb], [Mar]
FROM (
   SELECT ID, Name, Val, Mon,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name, Mon ORDER BY val) AS rn
   FROM (
      SELECT ID, Name, Jan, Feb, Mar
      FROM mytable ) p
   UNPIVOT 
      (Val FOR Mon IN (Jan, Feb, Mar) ) AS unpvt
) src
PIVOT (
   MAX(Val) FOR Mon IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar]) ) AS pvt
```

Using [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) you can get rid of all `NULL` values contained in `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar` columns. You can then use `PIVOT` to reconstruct the table to its initial form.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e57796/3)

**EDIT:**

If you don't want the `ID`, `Name` values repeated over successive rows, then you'd better handle this on the client side, as this is rather a data formatting requirement.

Anyway, you can easily achieve this effect with pure SQL using `rn` of the inner sub-query:

```
SELECT CASE when rn = 1 THEN CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)) ELSE '' END AS ID, 
       CASE when rn = 1 THEN Name ELSE '' END AS Name, 
       [Jan], [Feb], [Mar]      
FROM (
   SELECT ID, Name, Val, Mon,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name, Mon ORDER BY val) AS rn
   FROM (
      SELECT ID, Name, Jan, Feb, Mar
      FROM mytable ) p
   UNPIVOT 
      (Val FOR Mon IN (Jan, Feb, Mar) ) AS unpvt
) src
PIVOT (
   MAX(Val) FOR Mon IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar]) ) AS pvt
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e57796/8)

Comment: Can you please help without using pivot

Comment: @user3510028 You can search here in SO to find ways to simulate `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` operators.

Comment: It worked thanks, but I have updated the question can you help? that ID and name should not be repeated. @giorgos Betsos

Answer (score 0):

```
select   1 ID, 'xyz' Name, 1 Jan,  null Feb, null Mar into #temp union all select
1,  'xyz', 2 ,  null ,null  union all select
1,  'xyz' , null , 3 , null union all select
1,  'xyz',  null, null, 4 

select * from #temp

;with x as(
select ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by id,name, case when jan is null then null else 1 end,
 case when feb is null then null else 1 end,
  case when mar is null then null else 1 end order by name,id) rid,ID,name,jan,feb,mar from #temp
)
select ID, name, SUM(jan)jan, SUM(feb) feb, SUM(mar) mar from x group by rid,ID,name
```

**RESULT**

```
ID          name jan         feb         mar
----------- ---- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           xyz  1           3           4
1           xyz  2           NULL        NULL
```